# Pandas UDF returns dataframe without data

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Good day!

I am trying to apply very simple Pandas UDF in pyspark (Spark 2.4.5), however it does not work for me. Example:

```
pyspark --master local[4] --conf "spark.pyspark.python=/opt/anaconda/envs/bd9/bin/python3" --conf "spark.pyspark.driver.python=/opt/anaconda/envs/bd9/bin/python3"



 >>> my_df = spark.createDataFrame(
...     [
...         (1, 0),
...         (2, 1),
...         (3, 1),
...     ],
...     ["uid", "partition_id"]
... )

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

schema = StructType([StructField("uid", StringType())])

from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
import pandas

>>> @pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
... def apply_model(sample_df):
...     print(sample_df)
...     return pandas.DataFrame({"uid": sample_df["uid"]})
...

>>> result = my_df.groupBy("partition_id").apply(apply_model)
>>> result.show()
   uid  partition_id
0    1             0
[Stage 13:==================================================>    (92 + 4) / 100]   uid  partition_id
0    2             1
1    3             1
+---+
|uid|
+---+
|  |
|  |
|  |
+---+
```

Somehow uid's are not reflected in result.

Could you say what I am missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my bad, I wrote wrong type in schema, should be LongType() instead of StringType()